# Ordenar y comparar fichero en Java

Tags: java

Necesito comparar el contenido de dos archivos grandes (en este caso 600 kb) pero el problema es que la información viene en diferente orden en cada fichero.
Ahora meto el contenido de cada fichero en unArraylist y ordeno el arraylist, el problema es que no me los ordena igual por lo que al compararlos sale siempre ko.

```
public static void main (String [] arg) {
    ordenar();
}

public static void ordenar() {

    try {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader ("C:\\Users\\quality\\Desktop\\automatizacion\\modificados\\pruebaGenerado\\BEIPARAMXXX_0021_0001_NOTYPE.FIM_20200416_00004031");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\quality\\Desktop\\automatizacion\\modificados\\pruebaGenerado\\generado.txt");

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

        String linea = null;

        while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null){
            lista.add(linea);
        }

        Collections.sort(lista);

        Iterator iter = lista.iterator();

        String cadena;

        while (iter.hasNext())
        {
            cadena = (String) iter.next();
            pw.println(cadena);
            System.out.println(cadena);
        }

        br.close();
        fr.close();
        pw.close();
        fw.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}
```

Comment: Veo que ordenas el primer archivo, pero no veo que hagas lo mismo con el segundo archivo. Si quieres que queden con el mismo orden. al segundo fichero hazle lo mismo que haces con el primer fichero.

Comment: Hago lo mismo pero cambiando el fichero a ordenar en el codigo.

Comment: Dime algo, quieres que en el nuevo fichero quede lo que contienen los otros ficheros pero ordenados?? si es así puedo compartirte algo que tengo para que lo uses como ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

*Te dejo el siguiente ejemplo para que veas el funcionamiento. Se puede optimizar mas el código de como lo hice pero ya queda a tu disposición hacerlo.*

```js
public class Question346603Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> fichero1 = obtenerFichero("C:\\Users\\user\\eclipse\\workspace\\stackoverflow\\stackoverflow\\fichero1.txt");
        List<String> fichero2 = obtenerFichero("C:\\Users\\user\\eclipse\\workspace\\stackoverflow\\stackoverflow\\fichero2.txt");

        System.out.println("FICHERO 1");
        for (String linea : fichero1) {
            System.out.println(linea);
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        System.out.println("FICHERO 2");
        for (String linea : fichero2) {
            System.out.println(linea);
        }

        List<String> fichero3 = fichero1;
        fichero3.addAll(fichero2);

        Collections.sort(fichero3);

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\user\\eclipse\\workspace\\stackoverflow\\stackoverflow\\fichero3.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        System.out.println("\n\n");
        System.out.println("FICHERO 3");
        for (String linea : fichero3) {
            pw.println(linea);
            System.out.println(linea);
        }

        pw.close();
        fw.close();
    }

    private static List<String> obtenerFichero(String fichero) {
        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {

            FileReader fr = new FileReader (fichero);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            /*FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\quality\\Desktop\\automatizacion\\modificados\\pruebaGenerado\\generado.txt");

            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);*/


            String linea = null;

            while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null){
                lista.add(linea);
            }

            /*Collections.sort(lista);
            String cadena;

            for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
                cadena = lista.get(i);
                pw.println(cadena);
                System.out.println(cadena);
            }*/

            br.close();
            fr.close();
            /*pw.close();
            fw.close();*/

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return lista;
    }
}
```

*Lo he desmenuzado de esta manera para que puedas ver el funcionamiento correcto en cada proceso.*

*Lo primero que hice es obtener la información de cada fichero por separado para luego imprimirlos tal cual como los recibe, he creado un tercer **ArrayList** el cual obtendrá la información de los 2 ficheros obtenidos anteriormente y posteriormente este es ordenado. Luego lo imprimimos mientras vamos almacenando la información en un tercer fichero. que a disposición para que lo pruebes es cuestión de que modifiques las rutas y listo.*

*Espero te sirva.*

Comment: Perfecto me sirvio muy bien muchas gracias.

Comment: vale, me alegro poder haber sido de ayuda.